# Modify theme to get page excerpts on front page

Tags: pages, themes, query-posts, get-posts

I am trying to modify [this](http://www.2035themes.com/muusico/) theme so that the Latest News section shows excerpts from 3 specific *pages* (for example, /page1, /page2, /page3) instead of 3 most recent *posts*.

This is the relevant code in homepage.php

```
      <div class="homepage-news clearfix">
        <div class="latestnew title"><h3><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i><?php echo __( 'LATEST NEWS', '2035Themes-fm' ); ?></h3></div>
        <?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'showposts=3' ); ?>
        <?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
          <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4></a>
          <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
          <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><strong><?php echo __("Read More","theme2035-fm"); ?></strong></a>
        </div>
        <?php endwhile;?>
      </div>
```

What do I need to edit here to pull pages instead of posts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the [`post__in`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters)  parameter and pass an array of the page **ID's** to the parameter.

You can do the following: (*Note: you need to use the array syntax in `WP_Query` if you pass `post__in` as an argument*)

```
 <?php $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'page', 'post__in' => array( 1, 2, 3 ) ) ); ?>
```

Just change 1, 2, and 3 to the correct page ids

### EDIT

If you need to retain the order in which the pages are displayed according to the sequence passed to `post__in`, you can simply add `'orderby' => 'post__in'` to your arguments

```
 <?php $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'page', 'post__in' => array( 3, 1, 2 ), 'orderby' => 'post__in' ) ); ?>
```

This code will result in page 3 being displayed 1st, page 1 2nd and page 2 3rd

Comment: Thanks!  Just tried it, and the Latest news section is blank now.  Nothing is pulled.

Comment: Are you passing the correct ids

Comment: Yes, I am using 4-digit IDs as shown in the /wp-admin/post.php?post=xxxx&action=edit link in the Dashboard.

Comment: Do you get an array of post objetcs or an empty array when you do  `var_dump( $the_query->posts );` after your query

Comment: I am not sure how to find that out.  Could you guide me?

Comment: Just add `var_dump( $the_query->posts );` in between any php tags after the query

Comment: OK.  I get `array(0) { }`

Comment: I have update my code. Pass the post type to the query

Comment: Getting closer!  The pages excerpts are pulling now, but I can't seem to force the order in which they're sorted.  The /about-us/ page, for example, is always shown 3rd, probably because it has the highest post number.  Can the query be modified to force the order?

Comment: Just pass `'orderby' => 'post__in',` in your array of arguments. This will order the posts in the order they were passed to the `post__in` parameter

Comment: My pleasure. Enjoy :-)